# add animation to an tab navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-animate

I was wondering what could be the easiest way to add animation to some tab navigation.
I'm developing a small documentation website, [Documentation](http://rolandgroza.com/projects/doc/), and as you can see I have that small arrow that adds up to the tab when navigation.

Well, what I was thinking is what if I can do it like this : [Sample](http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Glider/) ; I tried something, I added a span via JS and then on click event ( applied to the `li` elements ) trigger the arrow animation. The thing is that doing that I stopped the script which is responsible for making the tabs work as they do stop.

So is there another way to achieve something like that ? And what would be the logic ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? animate that little arrow?

Comment: Yes, the same as the Glider theme does, but at the current state I'm using the `:after` pseudo element which I'm sure I cannot animate it. But as I described, I tried a different way without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest would be to add a narrow absolute position div inside st_slide_container and position to the right. Inside that new element add another element that is just large enough for your arrow icon and is position absolute.

Either use callback of tabs change( depends on what is available in plugin API) or add another click handler to a.st_tab.
In this event handler  you can get the index of current tab and apply animation of position top to the small arrow element

EDIT: Example of click handler to get index which would be multiplier for the `top` animation

```
$('a.st_tab').click(function(){
   alert($(this).parent().index())
})
```

Comment: The first thing you mentioned is what I tried, the only problem was that by binding a click event to the `li` elements I stopped the jQuery Plugin that is responsible for the tab navigation. I'm not sure if this plugin has a callback, which it should have, but I already asked that and I am waiting for an answer. And yes, attaching the click event to the `href` tag inside would be a good idea too, if I cannot do it like my previous idea I shall try doing what you suggested.

Comment: I ran the code I gave you in console on your page and it didn't interfere with tab navigation

Comment: Try now the link : http://rolandgroza.com/projects/doc/ ; uncomment the `.animate()` line in the main.js and see that it stops the other script from working, the tabs no longer change. What should I do ?

Comment: In fact I had to do it like this : `$('.st_tabs').on('click', 'a', function(){});` ; to make it work :)